# DotNetZip, ¿Cómo extraer un archivo ZIP con ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El problema es que al usar los eventos `ExtractProgress` y el `ZipProgress` no consigo encontrar la manera de hacerlo funcionar.

La referencia que usé es la [Clase ExtractProgressEventArgs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318173650/http://dotnetzip.herobo.com:80/DNZHelp/html/91d797c7-efff-99a3-2b14-6c9a9797b324.htm) y mi código:

```
try
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(dir_instancias_zip))
    {
        // Loop through the archive's files.
        foreach (ZipEntry zip_entry in zip)
        {
            zip.ExtractProgress += zipProgress;
            zip.ZipProgress += zipProgress;
            zip_entry.Extract(dir_instancias_temp);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error extracting archive.\n" + ex.Message);
}

private void zipProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e, ZipProgressEventArgs i)
{
    if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_AfterExtractEntry)
    {
        Progressbar_instalcion.Value = e.EntriesExtracted * 100 / i.EntriesTotal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Estuve en la búsqueda de la documentación, al menos para ayudarte, y no encontré rastro. Además, buscando entre los paquetes en Nuget solo encontré [`DotNetZip`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/), el cual hace referencia al sitio [DotNetZip.Semverd](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd).
>
> Existe una pregunta similar en SO: [DotNetZip - Display progress of extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948801/457643) dónde quizás te ayude en la implementación.

---

Revisando tu código, la asignación del evento debería ser antes del *foreach*.

```
try
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(dir_instancias_zip))
    {
        zip.ExtractProgress += zipProgress;
        
        foreach (ZipEntry zip_entry in zip)
        {
            zip_entry.Extract(dir_instancias_temp);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error extracting archive.\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Asimismo, deberías considerar los *bytes* que sea realiza duración la extracción.

```
private void zipProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_EntryBytesWritten)
    {
        Progressbar_instalcion.Value = (int)(e.BytesTransferred / (e.TotalBytesToTransfer * 0.01))
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando termina de descomprimir es cuando varia el prograssbar y ademas salta de 0% a 100% de golpe, igualmente muchas gracias por la ayuda